# RxJS Observables, check cache before making API request

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I'm creating an Angular app and have an API service. My `get` method only makes an HTTP call if the requested data isn't in the cache. I'm using the Promise-based LocalForage library, and transform them into Observables.

```
export class CacheService {
  get(prop: string) {
    return Observable.fromPromise(localForage.getItem(prop));
  }
```

Now in my API service, I'm racing my cache and http observables like so:

```
export class ApiService {
  get(uri: string) {
      return Observable.race(
        this.cache
          .get(uri)
          .filter(res => !!res),

        this.http.get(uri)
      );
  }
}
```

Since `Observable.race` only returns the observable that emits *first*, I thought that as long I'm using that `.filter()` operator, everything would work out. However, neither of them are returning if the data isn't in the cache, so the HTTP request is never being made. If someone could point out my mistake or suggest a better solution, I'm all ears.

Comment: Where's your subscribe?

Comment: @YakovFain thank you for replying. I'm sure that my subscribe isn't the issue, because if I remove the `.filter`, then I get a response of null, because the cache doesn't have anything yet.

Comment: @yazeedb Hmm.... The `Observable.race` behavior seems strange to me. It sends `complete` notification when one of the sources complete (because of https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/OuterSubscriber.ts#L20-L22) as mentioned by Federico Galassi in the answer but it guess this isn't expected behavior.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is `race` completes as soon as one of the observables is completed. Your cache call doesn't emit the null but completes immediately. You can use `merge` to keep going after completion and `take(1)` to consider the first result only:

```
export class ApiService {
  get(uri: string) {
      return Observable.merge(
        this.cache
          .get(uri)
          .filter(res => !!res),

        this.http.get(uri)
      ).take(1);
  }
}
```